# How to setup a UICollectionView with dynamic height and dynamic cell widths programmatically?

Tags: swift

I am trying to setup UICollectionView with a dynamic height and dynamic cell widths like the image below:

[image]

I've been only working with UIStackViews for my project, so UICollectionViews are new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you'll need to create a custom collectionViewLayout by creating a new class that is extending UICollectionViewFlowLayout and in that class you'll need to override the layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) method.
In that overridden method, what you'll be doing is basically that you'll be calculating the position for each cell again by modifying the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes of each cell, and then returning that new modified UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for each cell.

```
class LeftAlignedCellsCustomFlowLayout:UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {

//get an array of UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for all the cells
        let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)

        var leftMargin = sectionInset.left

        var maxY: CGFloat = 2.0

        let horizontalSpacing:CGFloat = 5

//Modify the UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes for each cell
        attributes?.forEach { layoutAttribute in

            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY
                || layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x == sectionInset.left {

                leftMargin = sectionInset.left
            }

            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x == sectionInset.left {
                leftMargin = sectionInset.left
            }else {
                layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin
            }

            leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + horizontalSpacing

            maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY, maxY)
        }
//return the array of modified UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
        return attributes
    }
}
```

Then in your View where you want to put this custom aligned CollectionView do the following:

```
  //Let's say you have an IBOutlet of your collectionView as a class-level instance
    @IBOutlet weak var leftAlignedCollectionView: UICollectionView!

//put the following code in the awakeFromNib of your View:
    let layout = LeftAlignedCellsCustomFlowLayout()
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 5
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5
    leftAlignedCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

Now, all you have to do is make a collectionViewCell which has a label inside it having left,right, top, bottom spacing. And, Inside the cell class put the following code:

```
var isHeightCalculated: Bool = false

override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

        //We need to cache our calculation to prevent a crash.

        if !isHeightCalculated {

            layoutIfNeeded()
            let size = contentView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(layoutAttributes.size)
            var newFrame = layoutAttributes.frame
            newFrame.size.width = CGFloat(ceilf(Float(size.width)))
            layoutAttributes.frame = newFrame
            isHeightCalculated = true

        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }
```

The overriding of the above method Gives the cell a chance to modify the attributes provided by the layout object.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I'll try this and let you know if it helped!

Comment: @Jnguyen22 Did you try it? Please mark this answer to be the correct one if this has solved your problem. Else, let me know what challenges you are facing.

Comment: Sorry for getting back so late. Do I put the custom aligned CollectionView in my awakeFromNib if I'm trying to do all of this programatically?

Comment: @Jnguyen22 I have edited that part of the answer.
Please check and let me know.